# How to reverse string in snowflake function (javascript)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION instr_reverse(st string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS ' 
    var temp = ST.split("")
    var temp1 = temp.reverse()
    var temp2 = temp1.join()
    return temp2
';
```

function error -> unknown function reverse

Comment: Hi, if you want to reserve a string in Snowflake then why don't you use the RESERVE function in Snowflake, or is it something else that you want to do ?  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/reverse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Himanshu mentioned there is a function for this: REVERSE

```
select REVERSE('GOKHAN');
```

Anyway, as I like to write JavaScript functions, I checked your script, and it worked on me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION instr_reverse(st string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS ' 
    var temp = ST.split("")
    var temp1 = temp.reverse()
    var temp2 = temp1.join("")
    return temp2
';


select instr_reverse( 'gokhan' );
```

Answer (score 0):

JS supports method chaining:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PUBLIC.instr_reverse(st string)
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS ' 
    return ST.split("").reverse().join("");
';

select PUBLIC.instr_reverse('Hello World');
-- dlroW olleH
```

If the goal is to reverse word order:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION instr_reverse(st string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS ' 
    return ST.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
';

select PUBLIC.instr_reverse('Hello World');
-- World Hello
```